# Contact form 7 save into DB - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I'm trying to insert a custom function in the function.php to copy more simply how to make plug-ins prepared, the data of a form filled out and sent. server sends me an error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$formDB' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\AppServ\www\ITI\SITO\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\includes\functions.php on line 375
```

this is my code:

```
 remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
 add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );

 function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {

global $wpdb;

$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) 
    $formDB = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();


$datains = now();
$username = $formDB['your-name'] $formDB['your-surname'];
$email = $formDB['your-email'];
$tel = $formDB['your-tel'];
$orario = $formDB['orario'];
$CentriITI = $formDB['CentriITI'];
$citta = $formDB['citta'];
$fasciadieta = $formDB['fasciadieta'];
$checkbox-info-sedi = $formDB['checkbox-info-sedi'];
$checkbox-checkup = $formDB['checkbox-checkup'];
$object = $formDB['your-object'];
$checkbox-trapianto = $formDB['checkbox-trapianto'];
$textarea-testo = $formDB['textarea-testo'];



$wpdb->insert( 'wp_form', array( 'datains' =>; $datains_form ), array( 'username_form' =>; $username ), array( 'email_form' =>; $email ) ,array( 'tel_form' =>; $tel ), array( 'orario_form' =>; $orario ), array( 'centro_form' =>; $centro ), array( 'citta_form' =>; $citta ), array( 'fasciaeta_form' =>; $fasciaeta ), array( 'object_form' =>; $object ), array( 'trapianto_form' =>; $checkbox-trapianto ) );
```

}

Thanks for the answers

Comment: these: `'datains' =>; $datains_form` should look like this `'datains' =>$datains_form`

Comment: Adding to @admcfajn's comment, you should also use one single array containing all the key value pairs, see the [examples in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row).